# "Upgrading" an SQLAlchemy object to a derived class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given these two models:

```
class Game(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'games'
  type = Column(String(11))
      __mapper_args__ = {
          'polymorphic_identity': 'game',
          'polymorphic_on': type,
      }

class HostedGame(Game):
    __tablename__ = 'hosted_games'
    name = Column(String, ForeignKey('games.name'), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'hosted_game',
        'inherit_condition': (name == Game.name),
    }
```

If I have in my database a Game object, and I wish to turn it into a HostedGame, what is the best approach? Struggling at the moment to find a simple answer for this given that, in pure SQL, it would simply be a case of inserting a row into the hosted_games table and be done with it.

I can manage this if I use two separate transactions, one for deleting the existing Game and another for inserting the new HostedGame, but if the second transaction breaks then I can't easily roll back the first, so I'd really like to do it in a single transaction. However, something like this:

```
            async with session.begin()
              new_hosted_game = await create_hosted_game_object_from_game(game)
              new_hosted_game.attr1 = new_host_attr1
              # etc
              await session.delete(game)
              session.add(new_hosted_game)
```

Doesn't work, which probably reveals my lack of understanding with ORMs.

The error:

```
E   sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: UPDATE statement on table 'hosted_games' expected to update 1 row(s); 0 were matched.
```

Is there a really easy to achieve this that I've missed, or should I come at it from another angle? Many thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the structure here: it looks as if there is a many to one relation between Game and HostedGame, in which case, how can you delete the "parent" object when creating a "child"?  Are you trying to create one of the inheritance hierarchies described [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/inheritance.html)?

Comment: @snakecharmerb there should only be a 1:1 relationship between Game/ HostedGame, but they don't have any relationship with other Game/HostedGames. I want these two objects to behave as typical polymorphic objects, with instances of Game existing and also instances of HostedGame. The issue I'm having is essentially with converting a Game into a HostedGame in a single transaction. As far as I'm aware my setup is using Joined Table inheritance but I could be misunderstanding something?

Comment: "converting a Game into a HostedGame" -> what does this entail? (or, what is `create_hosted_game_object_from_game` supposed to do?)

Comment: @snakecharmerb simply creating a new HostedGame object and setting its attributes to match that of the original Game object, plus initializing the HostedGame's specific attributes.
to reframe it, I have an "Employee" object in the DB that tracks a generic employee, but now I want that Employee to be recorded as a "Manager" instead, so outside of the ORM I create a new Manager class using Employee's attributes. This is effectively what I'm doing, the problem I'm having is creating the new Manager and deleting the old Employee in a single async transaction